# Are there any good Android tutorials for launching applications?

Tags: android

I want to create an android application that launches an application on handwriting recognition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to handle gestures is aptly described here [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23134582/3364905)

You need save and record the gesture in a file. After you save the gesture then you can copy the saved gesture file to your /res/raw folder, load it, and attach a gesture listener as explained in above answer.

And method to launch another application is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3872063/3364905)